# Making nav bar effects using scroll AND click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a nav to highlight (or something similar) once a user clicks on it AND when a user scrolls to the corresponding section.

However, on my computer when one clicks on any of the nav events after3, only nav event 3 changes. I'm guessing this is because after one clicks on 4 or 5, the scroll bar is already at the bottom of the page, so 4 and 5 never reach the top. The only div at the top is post 3, so my code highlights nav event 3 and ignores the click.

Is there any way I can fix this? Ive tried if statements (only highlight nav event if it's at the top AND the scrollbar isn't at the bottom or the top isn't the last item).

Here is a more accurate [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n44RU/4/), using a fix below showing what I am talking about. The fix now highlights on scroll, but if you click option 5, it will not highlight.

```
$('.option').children('a').click(function() {
    $('.option').css('background-color', '#CCCCCC;');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    var postId = $($(this).attr('href'));
    var postLocation = postId.offset().top;
    $(window).scrollTop(postLocation);
});
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollBar = $(this).scrollTop();
    var allPosts = [];
    var post = $('.content').offset();
    var lastPost = allPosts.legnth-1
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var bottomScroll = windowHeight-scrollBar;
    $(".content").each(function(){            
        allPosts.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });
    i = 0;
    for(i in allPosts){
        var currentPost = "#"+allPosts[i];
        var postPosition = $(currentPost).offset().top;
        if (scrollBar >= postPosition){
            $('.option').css('background-color', '#CCCCCC');
            $('#nav'+allPosts[i]).css('background-color', 'red');
        }; 
    }; 
});
```

Comment: You have to add jQuery to your fiddle. Look: http://jsfiddle.net/n44RU/1/

Comment: ARG. I always forget to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've overdone your `scroll()` handler, to keep it simple you just needs to check if the scrollbar/`scrollTop` reaches the `'.contents'` offset top value but should not be greater than its `offset().top` plus its `height()`.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollBar = $(this).scrollTop();

    $(".content").each(function (index) {
        var elTop = $(this).offset().top;
        var elHeight = $(this).height();

        if (scrollBar >= elTop - 5 && scrollBar < elTop + elHeight) {
            /* $(this) '.content' is the active on the vewport, 
               get its index to target the corresponding navigation '.option',
               like this - $('.Nav li').eq(index)    
            */
        }
    });
});
```

And you actually don't need to set `$(window).scrollTop(postLocation);` because of the default `<a>` tag anchoring on click, you can omit that one and it will work fine. However if you are looking to `animate` you need first to prevent this default behavior:

```
$('.option').children('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var postId = $($(this).attr('href'));
    var postLocation = postId.offset().top;

    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:postLocation},'slow');
});
```

See the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n44RU/3/).

Comment: Thanks but I offered a bad example. Can you check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n44RU/4/)

It recreates the problem I was going through, using your code. When I click the fifth option, it doesn't highlight it.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n44RU/4/)

Comment: Yes because we rely on `scroll()` event to move the 'active' class. As you can see on the demo when you reached somewhere on article 3 you've also reached the bottom because article 4 and 5 are too short so we can't move to them. To solve this issue we should also assign 'active' on `click()`, since we're also animate the anchoring we should execute this on `animate() complete` see this updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n44RU/7/).

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to implement from scratch, although commendable, has already been done by the nice folks at Bootstrap. It is called a Scrollspy and all you need to do to implement it is include Bootstrap js and css (you also need jquery but you already have that) and make some minor changes to your html.

[Scrollspy implementation steps.](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy)

[And here is a demonstration.](http://jsfiddle.net/6KuAw/) Notice only one line of js. :D

```
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '.navbar-example' });
```

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful, mostly because I forgot about scrollspy. Though I am trying to do everything from scratch because I am learning, and I feel like this should be simple.