# How to highlight right side dot bar on page scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please check this page: https://shibbir.dev/navigate-master/

Here you can see the **dot circle** on the right side. If you click on the **dot circle**, it will go to the **corresponding section** and **highlight** the dot circle. for e.g: If you click on the **2nd dot circle** it will go to the **About** section and will highlight the **2nd dot circle**.

Now, my question is how can I highlight the **corresponding dot circle** if I scroll the page?

**My Current HTML**

```
<div class="navigate-master">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" class="">&nbsp;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" class="active">&nbsp;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services" class="">&nbsp;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="">&nbsp;</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the JS is:

```
(function ($) {

    $(".navigate-master ul li a").on("click", function () {
        var el = $(this);
        $(".navigate-master ul li a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    })

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070666/making-nav-bar-effects-using-scroll-and-click-in-jquery) with a good answer to point you in the right direction.

Thinking through this at a high level what you need to do is:

- get the scrollTop position of each of the elements that represent the dots
- have an onscroll handler that checks which of the element's scroll top position is the greatest && <= the current scroll position (one solution, see the similar question for a different approach)
- then apply the active class to this HTML element and style accordingly

Hope this helps!